# Where is the layout editor?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Hi guys, just installed Android Studio into my Ubuntu 16.04, added all SDKs and the layout editor seems to not show up. Anybody can help?

Comment: Is there anything in that XML file? Click on the Text sub-tab (towards the bottom of the screen).

Comment: Yeah, there's Relative Layout and a BUtton

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this? It does not appear to be Android Studio 2.2, the current release version.

Comment: Did you try to click on that `refresh` button on the upper right corner of the LayoutEditor? It is to the left of the settings button. Also try to rebuild your project or restart the Android Studio